# Subjects created with Subject.create can't unsubscribe

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I have a subject that is responsible for subscriptions to certain observable:

```
var timer$ = Rx.Observable.timer(1000, 2000);
```

When the subject is linked to the subject like that

```
var timerSubject = new Rx.Subject;
timer$.subscribe(timerSubject);

var subscription1 = timerSubject.subscribe(n => console.log(n));
var subscription2 = timerSubject.subscribe(n => console.log(n));

setTimeout(() => timerSubject.unsubscribe(), 4000);
```

everything is fine, `timerSubject.unsubscribe()` can be called once and the subscriptions shouldn't be unsubscribed one by one.

When the subject is created with `Subject.create` like that (a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/sQ3inBq4xDXpCvlMXrPV?p=info))

```
var timerSubject = Rx.Subject.create(null, timer$);

var subscription1 = timerSubject.subscribe(n => console.log(n));
var subscription2 = timerSubject.subscribe(n => console.log(n));

setTimeout(() => timerSubject.unsubscribe(), 4000);
```

`timerSubject.unsubscribe()` does nothing, while I would expect to behave it the same as in the first snippet.

If `Subject.create` creates a subject that can't even unsubscribe, what's the purpose of `Subject.create` then?

Why does this happen? Is this a bug?

How can the subject should be created to reach the desired behaviour?

It is reproducible with RxJS 5 RC1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the [source code for `Subject.create()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/Subject.js.html#lineNumber19) and it's not the same as [calling `new Subject()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/Subject.js.html#lineNumber111).

- `Subject.create()` returns an instance of `AnonymousSubject`.
- `new Subject()` returns an instance of `Subject`.

So it seems the problem why `unsubscribe()` on `AnonymousSubject` doesn't work is because it in fact never subscribes. It just keeps a reference to the `source` Observable and when subscribing an Observer it connects directly `source` with the Observer and doesn't keep track of created subscribtions.

In your case when you call `timerSubject.subscribe()` it subscribes directly to `timer$` and `AnonymousSubject` acts only as mediator.

I don't know whether this is by design or it's a bug. However, the first option is more likely I think.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the thing on `_subscribe`, Yes, this explains why subscribers aren't pushed to `observers` and thus are not unsubscribed. I wonder what's the proper way then to embrace an observable with subject to achieve the thing I'm trying to do.

Comment: I think this is just not how `AnonymousSubject` is supposed to be used. Although, there's no official documentation available yet I guess the only option is to unsubscribe both `subscription1` and `subscription2` manually. http://plnkr.co/edit/4sdGqPiEnTrrgXUuVive