# RxJs Subject.subscribe method not working as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

`Subject.subscribe` method when called outputs the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_subscribe' of undefined
at BidirectionalSubject._subscribe (Rx.js:10239)
at BidirectionalSubject._subscribe (Rx.js:10239)
at BidirectionalSubject.Observable.subscribe (Rx.js:9924)
at AppComponent.doIt (app.component.ts:32)
at ChangeDetector_AppComponent_0.handleEventInternal (eval at ChangeDetectorJITGenerator.generate (angular2.dev.js:1), <anonymous>:29:29)
at ChangeDetector_AppComponent_0.AbstractChangeDetector.handleEvent (angular2.dev.js:8788)
at AppView.dispatchEvent (angular2.dev.js:9396)
at AppView.dispatchRenderEvent (angular2.dev.js:9391)
at DefaultRenderView.dispatchRenderEvent (angular2.dev.js:7819)
at eventDispatcher (angular2.dev.js:9781)
```

### See Plunkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/UYJJuFeR1ZrWAPaxsA8D).

---

This is a part of a bigger problem I am facing. **In my actual code, the `subscribe` method does not throw but it simply does not add an `observer` to the `subject`, and hence on all `subject.next` invocations no one receives the emitted data.**

I think the problems are related. In my actual code I am using version `5.0.0-beta.12` of rxjs. In the plukr though, the `rx` dependency seems to be coming from angular itself.

Comment: You're using old RxJS version, where [these safeguards](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subject.ts#L156-L160) probably don't exist. As the answer explains, you shouldn't use Subject.create, it is for creating proxy subjects, it is useless without arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Be aware of using `Subject.create()`.**

This is not the same as `new Subject()` and absolutely most of the time you want to use just `new Subject()` instead of `Subject.create()`. With `Subject.create()` you're creating an instance of `AnonymousSubject` which never subscribes itself and therefore the `flatMap()` operator throws an error when trying to subscribe `AnonymousSubject` to another `AnonymousSubject`.

See my answer to a similar question: [Subjects created with Subject.create can't unsubscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40159886/subjects-created-with-subject-create-cant-unsubscribe/40164700#40164700).

I just changed `Subject.create()` to `new Subject()` and it's probably working.

See your updated demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/6M1lPLZA16vwQsVAjNzc?p=preview

Although, I don't know what's that demo supposed to do so I can't tell whether it's working correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Coming from a RxJava background this was the last place I'd have looked. In RxJava one creates Subjects via the `static create` method almost exclusively. 

The demo is working correctly, although it is not at all close to the(any) real world problem I was solving, it was just and MWE.

Also, could anyone elaborate on why there is a behavior difference between `Subject.create()` and `new Subject()`.

Comment: @tMJ I think `AnonymousSubject` makes sense and is useful (see the related question and although I've never used it in practise myself) the `Subject.create()` is very confusing. As you can see you're not the first one stumbling on this.