# Subject vs AnonymousSubject

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

What's the difference between `Subject` and `AnonymousSubject` in *RxJS 5*?
I've searched the internet but didn't find any info about `AnonymousSubject`.

I've found an example on the web

```
Subject.create(observer, observable);
```

Looking into rxjs source code I saw that this creates and `AnonymousSubject`.
Can you also come up with an example when is good to use `AnonymousSubject`?

Comment: There is a use case in the RxJS4 documentation: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/subject.md#example-1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `AnonymousSubject` doesn't subscribe itself to the source Observable. It just connects the `source` and `destination`.

I don't know what a typical use-case for `AnonymousSubject` looks like but it's used inside [`Subject.lift()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subject.ts#L46).

Also see: [RxJs Subject.subscribe method not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40361623/rxjs-subject-subscribe-method-not-working-as-expected/40362172#40362172)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `AnonymousSubject` to define an operator that returns a hot observable. Usually the Observable will be a Subject too, for example a `BehaviorSubject`.

On the Observer side, the `onNext` method will "do something" with the value it receives and push to the destination Subject. For example an the observer could accept a boolean value for "is the network connection available", try connecting to a server when the network connection becomes available, and push true to a BehaviorSubject if the attempt to connect succeeds. This `AnonymousSubject` would tell you upon subscription whether you are connected to the server.