# RXJS Subject, return the same value on every first subscribe

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I know I need to use `startWith`, but still trying to figure out how to use it. If I just do `Subject.create().startWith("Some Value)`, it turns the `Subject` into a `Observable`, and I can't use `next` to emit.

So multiple subscribers should be able `subscribe` to it. Should be able to call `next` on the `Subject`. Going through the docs of `Subject.create()`, but it's going slow.

**Edit:**
I got it to work after using the accepted solution. The reason why it wasn't working before was because I put the `.next` call inside the subscription.

Eg:

```
observable.subscribe((res) => {
// do something
s.next('another res');
}
```

This creates an infinite loop, and I think RXJS prevented it? Anyway, I put the `next` in there for debug purposes. I moved it outside of that `subscribe` block and now and initial result emits, then when `next` is called, whatever was inside `subscribe` emit again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using `Subject.create()` and use just `Subject()`. See: [Subject vs AnonymousSubject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148463/subject-vs-anonymoussubject)

Just keep a reference to the Subject instance and another reference to the Observable chain you need:

```
let s = new Subject();
let observable = s.startWith("Some initial message");

observable.subscribe(...);
s.next('whatever');
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but the observable doesn't emit when I call `next` on the `s`

Comment: Thanks martin, I think RXJS blocked my silly infinite loop when I put `next` inside the subscribe for debug purposes. Moved it out side and now both initial and next gets through.