# Rx.Subject.create(observer, observable) confusion

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observer-pattern, observers, reactivex

In the [API documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/subject.md) it says

> Arguments
>
> 1. observer (Observer): The observer used to send messages to the subject.
> 2. observable (Observable): The observable used to subscribe to messages sent from the subject.

But isn't the concept backwards in that the observer is supposed to be receiving/handling messages emitted from the subject, and the observable is what the subject would be subscribed to? The API doc and the [getting started with subjects doc](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md) don't seem consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is already answered here: [Subjects created with Subject.create can't unsubscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40159886/subjects-created-with-subject-create-cant-unsubscribe/40164700#40164700)

`Subject.create` is a static method that just connects the Observable with an observer. No instance of `Subject` is involved.

What you're describing looks more like multicasting so maybe have a look at `multicast()` operator or its derivatives.

Also see:

- [RxJs Subject.subscribe method not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40361623/rxjs-subject-subscribe-method-not-working-as-expected/40362172#40362172)
- [Subject vs AnonymousSubject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148463/subject-vs-anonymoussubject/42154109#42154109)

Comment: Ok, sounds simple enough, but if Subject.create() is just connecting the given Observable to the given Observer, why does the API doc for the Subject.create() arguments even mention a subject entity as some sort of proxy? And why does it mention an Observer as "sending messages" and an Observable as "subscribing to messages"? Is the doc simply wrong?

Comment: @solstice333 You're referring to RxJS 4, which is old. What I wrote here refers to RxJS 5.