# rxjs Subject.create deprecated - what should I use instead?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this code in a service in my Angular app:

```
const subby = Subject.create(observer, observable)
```

But my IDE correctly marks `Subject.create` as deprecated. What should I use instead thanks? I've tried `new Subject(observer, observable)` but no joy. TIA.

> RxJS version: 6.4.0
>
> Angular version: 7.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the source code, the static function `Subject.create(destination, source)` is just a wrapper around `new AnonymousSubject<T>(destination, source)`.

If you're just looking to deal with the warning, you can change your code to

```
import { AnonymousSubject } from 'rxjs/internal/Subject';

const subby = new AnonymousSubject<T>(observer, observable);
```

---

RxJs has documented their motivation for this change [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3982). The important quote:

> Subject.create doesn't actually create a Subject, but rather an
>   AnonymousSubject, which I would REALLY like to rename as
>   FrankenSubject because that describes what it is, you basically glue
>   an Observer to an Observable and call it a "Subject".

In short, using `Subject.create` (or the `AnonymousSubject` object) is a confusing way of accomplishing your goals.

You can look at the source code for this class [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/Subject.js.html#lineNumber119), but the gist is that it's a pointless class that obfuscates what's going on. In the code, you can see that `destination` and `source` (the `Observer` and `Observable` arguments) have NO interaction.

So, the "right way" to fix the code is to murder this object entirely and be more explicit about how the relevant events are routed.

For example:

```
// This code...
const subby = Subject.create(observer, observable);
subby.subscribe((value: value) => console.log(value));
subby.next("Test");

// Should be replace by this code
// Nothing
observable.subscribe((value: value) => console.log(value));
observer.next("Test");
```

---

I also found the following warnings about using `Subject.create` that may be relevant for future readers:

- [Subjects created with Subject.create can't unsubscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40159886/subjects-created-with-subject-create-cant-unsubscribe/40164700#40164700)
- [Subject Subscribe method not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40361623/rxjs-subject-subscribe-method-not-working-as-expected/40362172#40362172)

Comment: @danday74 Did you ever get that "new way"?

Comment: here's a clue from a ts lint warning ... WARNING: C:/Users/daniel/Desktop/biblical-hebrew/biblical-hebrew-fe/src/app/services/websocket.service.ts[34, 29]: create is deprecated: use new Subject() instead

Comment: this still remains the one tslint warning in my codebase :(

Comment: @danday74 Updated with additional research. If that detail is not sufficient, I recommend you ask a new question with additional information such as what parameters you're using and how you're using the result

Answer (score 0):

Subject will not accept any arguments while creating. So you need to initialize it 
 like (`new Subject()`). After then you can use next method on it to emit value.